# dispatchTouchEvent() is not working in case of dialog and menu

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, touch-event, android-viewgroup

I am trying to perform programmatically click using view.

I am able to achieve this on normal UI if it is a button or a text or a list.

Here is my code:

`element.GetView().getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(mMotionEvent);`

this is working fine in case of normal window.
But when it comes to dialog list and menu item it is not working

here is class name this contains list of radio button attached to dialog.
`androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$RecycleListView`

here is class name this contains list of menu items attached to dialog.
`android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView`